# How to install latest munin server

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, raspbian-stretch, monitoring, make

If I install munin server from apt-get, only version `2.0.33-1` is installed which can't be started because `Failed to start munin.service: Unit munin.service is masked.`

make from source fails with

```
Can't locate MasterBuilder.pm in @INC (you may need to install the MasterBuilder module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.24.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.24.1 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl5/5.24 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.24 /usr/share/perl/5.24 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl-base) at Build.PL line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Build.PL line 1.
Makefile:452: recipe for target 'master/Build' failed
make: *** [master/Build] Error 2
```

I'm using Raspbian Stretch Lite (2018-04-18). What can I do?

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/79820/78211

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be the same issue as [bug #837788](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=837788) in the Debian bug tracker. It appears that this is actually by design, and Munin installed without any problems from the repo on your Pi:

> On Fri, 10 Mar 2017 at 07:46:17 +0100, Stig Sandbeck Mathisen wrote:
>
> > Munin needs /run/munin created with the correct permissions.
> >
> > When using sysv init, the /etc/init.d/munin script does that, and exits.
>
> Aha. So the boot process (systemd or sysvinit) in jessie and stretch
>   is not meant to start munin at all, only prepare the necessary
>   directory for it to be started by the web server?
>
> If that's the case, then perhaps this bug could be closed as "working
>   as intended", or downgraded to wishlist and retitled "systemctl
>   restart munin does nothing".

If you are having trouble with Munin, it is likely not due to the "masked" message from systemd; this is intentional.

Comment: Äh? I probably dont understand. How can I restart munin e.g. after some config changes?