# When under load, the system is unresponsive except for a ping

Tags: raspbian, ssh, power, troubleshooting, ping

I've got a Raspberry Pi 1 Model B that has been my trusty workhorse for a few years. It normally chugs away happily running transmission, pi-hole and a node.js app simultaneously.

All of a sudden it's started to become unresponsive under load. I can no longer SSH into it, but I can still ping it during this time. I can't access the transmission or pi-hole web clients when this happens either.

The only thing I can think of is that I've moved abroad and I'm now on a 120v circuit, but the power unit does say it's capable of running on 120-240v. It's a 5V 2A unit which has never caused me any problems in the UK.

What are some steps I could take to try and diagnose the problem?

Comment: If you've crossed the seas, you're likely on a different network.  What else is on this network?  What kind of router do you have?  Has anything else on your network gotten infected?

Comment: Have you tried swapping out the power supply and/or USB cable?

Comment: I've swapped the USB cable and it seems a little more stable, it might have deteriorated. I have a better router than before, nothing else on the network is struggling. Getting a lot of 'unable to save resume file: input / output error' with transmission...the HDD it's hooked up to was also at about 95% capacity so hopefully that will stop now. Possibly multiple issues manifesting at once..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the SD card was done for. This became apparent when trying to format it and it couldn't be done.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a monitoring tool, i.e. [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/):

> Munin is a networked resource monitoring tool that can help analyze resource trends and "what just happened to kill our performance?" problems.

source: http://munin-monitoring.org/

You can find an introductory guide and more options [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/79788/how-to-set-up-dashboard-for-monitoring-pi-processes/79820).