# How can I ping a command to a raspberry pi from my windows machine?

Tags: raspbian, windows

So I have a raspberry pi set up with my script on it, however I only want the script to run when I need it to, which isn't on a regular schedule...the best way for me to do this is to ping it(as my windows machine is my main computer).

In the command prompt I can ping the RPi IP address with `ping xxx.xxx.xx.xx`. Is there any way this can be adapted to send a command to my RPi rather than a generic response?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You cannot change what ping sends (in terms of it sending a command). I'd suggest instead running a web server (simple with Python sockets) that when called, calls the script you need to run.

Comment: you could use a serial connection via the USB

Comment: ...or SSH (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/).

Comment: Do you have PuTTY installed on Windows? PuTTY includes plink that can send commands to your Raspbian system from a Windows DOS cmd.exe https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.71/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink

Comment: Interesting question I think... re-purposing `ping` to send commands to a host. But after reading the documentation, you will understand this is not what `ping` is designed (or able) to do. There are likely many ways you could accomplish this, but then again, it may be far more effort than you're prepared for. I'd suggest you think through what it is you're trying to do, and consider other options for accomplishing it.

Comment: You might find some traction using `iptables`. [Read this Q&A](https://serverfault.com/a/209143/515728), then look into the `iptables` documentation to `log` that event, then write a script to monitor the log & take action when it occurs. Like I said... quite a bit of effort.

Comment: You can use socat and ncat for a simple one line port trigger see my answer here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/79824/71180

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking from [another answer of mine](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/79824/71180), the `socat` utility provides a convenient way to create this kind of "one-off" servelets. Your use case is very appropriate for this utility. `socat` is part of a suite of network "swiss-army-knife" tools along with `nc`(netcat)  and `ncat`

`socat` can be used to listen on a port, and run a command whenever a connection is made. This command can respond with text or data, but it does not have to.

`socat tcp4-listen:5000,reuseaddr,fork exec:'/home/pi/myscript_trigger.sh'`

If you need it to respond with use-able data (will echo everything script prints to shell)

`socat tcp4-listen:5000,reuseaddr,fork exec:'/home/pi/myscript_trigger.sh'`**`,pty,raw,echo=0`**

On another computer you can connect to this socket using a related net utility `nc`

```
$ nc my-pi.ip 5000
09:08:21 up 6 days,  1:35,  9 users,  load average: 0.07, 0.28, 0.25
```

or you can use socat as well

```
$ socat tcp4-connect:my-pi.ip:5000
```

(In this case the program triggered for demo is the system `uptime` utility)

Or Any number of other utilities that can connect to port and ip, many common terminal programs like `puTTY`, `minicom`, `picocom`, `screen`, and  `realterm` on both windows and linux can connect directly to a `host:port` and be the "source" of the trigger.

To **specifically** use ping (ICMP) to trigger, is a little more challenging, especially if you require that the ICMP response is issued as normal.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use `ssh` for this.

But if you want to do it with pings, you could try it by using `tcpdump`.

```
while true; 
do
  sudo tcpdump -i wlan0 -c 1  icmp and host 192.168.4.67 and 192.168.4.1 &&
  yourCommand
  sleep 1
done
```

The `tcpdump` command will exit if icmp (ping) is send between 192.168.4.67 and 192.168.4.1, which should be the ip addresses of your computer and pi.